# parameterized task to swap two values in SystemVerilog

Tags: swap, system-verilog

I want to write a generic-width `swap`, but I'm not sure what the syntax should be.

My first guess:

```
task automatic swap #( int W=1 ) ( ref logic [W-1:0] a, ref logic [W-1:0] b );
   begin
   automatic logic[W-1:0] temp=a; a=b; b=temp;
   end endtask
```

But I get the following error (from Cadence irun):

```
ncvlog: *E,SVNOCS: Class specialization syntax not allowed in method name for out-of-block method declaration.
```

Also, what is the syntax to invoke such a task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tasks and functions cannot have their own parameters. You can achieve the same effect by declaring a static method in a parameterized class. The methods can be made more generic by making the parameter a data type instead of a bit width. Example:

```
class generic #(type T=logic);
  // Note: you may want to replace 'ref' with 'inout'
  static function void swap( ref T a, b );
    {b,a} = {a,b};
  endfunction
endclass
```

Then somewhere in your code, you can do this like:

```
generic#(logic[4:0])::swap( my_a, my_b);
generic#(int)::swap( my_int_a, my_int_b);
generic#(my_struct_st)::swap( my_struct_a, my_struct_b);
generic#(my_class)::swap( my_class_a, my_class_b);
generic#(virtural my_interface)::swap( my_if_a, my_if_b);
```